# No me muestra el div

Tags: javascript, html, eventos

No me muestra el div con el id = dato al ejecutar el evento blur, al hacer click fuera del imput con id= nombre, espero puedan ayudarme se los agradezco
adjunto parte del codigo html:

```
#dato{
                padding: 10px;
                border-top: 10px;
                border: 4px dashed black;
                height: 40px;
                width: 250px;
                display: none;
                margin-top: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <boddy>
        <h1>Aprendiendo jQuery - Eventos</h1>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="nombre">
        </form>
        <div id="dato"> </div>
        <br>
        <div id="caja">
            Soy una caja
        </div>
    </boddy>
```

Adjunto parte del codigo de javascript

```
 var nombre = $("#nombre");
    nombre.focus(function(){
        $(this).css("border","2px solid red")
    });
    var datos = $("#dato");
    nombre.blur(function(){
        $(this).css("border","2px solid gray");
        console.log(datos)    
    });
```

Comment: "No me muestra el div" no es una pregunta. Cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: Falta incluir el  `datos.show();`

Comment: Esa respuesta la di yo hace cinco minutos, en vez de hacer un comentario, puedes validar mi respuesta y si alguien tiene un problema parecido y lo busca, saldra que esta cuestión esta respondida correctamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diría que no se muestra porque tienes un display: none. Tienes que cambiar ese estilo cuando llamas al evento blur. O en su defecto puedes probar a ponerle un show que te cambiara el valor de display a un valor que es visible.

```
var nombre = $("#nombre");
nombre.focus(function(){
    $(this).css("border","2px solid red");
});
var datos = $("#dato");
nombre.blur(function(){
    $(this).css("border","2px solid gray");
    datos.show(); // Muestra el div "dato"
    console.log(datos);    
});
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me funcionó